# Rails 4, Asset Compiling

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, assets

I have probably wasting 4 hours trying to make this problem go away and not sure what the problem is.

Locally I have been creating my Rails Application and all the assets load properly which can be see here:

```
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/auth.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/authenications.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/customelements.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/grid.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/home.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/material.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/materials.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/project_materials.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/projects.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/registrations.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/show.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/static.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/testing.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/grid.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/auth.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/authenications.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/grid.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/mat.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/material.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/materials.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/polygon.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/project_materials.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/projects.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/registrations.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/static.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/testing.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
```

So, cool it works in development mode... but then it doesn't work when I push to heroku!

```
<title>BuyABrick</title>
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application-5c6e8eba841451fd8e44660093bd224e.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/grid-fc208f1a1279c5b79eec166dc18c02f6.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application-6aa3a38ecf886de2bf443a2b4b67ab04.js"></script>
<meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="aCmkfVxhDEO4PtC3AdHhLZ9smJ+9shdchBT0mkYqQvM=" name="csrf-token" />
```

And when I click on the

```
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application-5c6e8eba841451fd8e44660093bd224e.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
```

the server returns to me an internal server error (**EDIT** Didn't realise that the HTML screws everything up here)

[image]

So I have tried all the soultions by researching the internet for everything known to man. Here are the files that I have...

**config/environment/production.rb**

```
BuyABrick::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "nill" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  config.assets.precompile += %w( application.css)

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

Any help will be appreciated.. if you want more code look into my github..

https://github.com/srizzling/BuyABrick

Thanks!

Heroku logs

```
$ heroku logs
2013-09-16T12:54:31.548606+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:140:in `variation'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.548606+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:133:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.548606+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.548606+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.548606+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.548606+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.548606+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.548787+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.548787+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.574177+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-6aa3a38ecf886de2bf443a2b4b67ab04.js host=buyabrickonline.herokuapp.com fwd="115.188.114.182" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=24ms status=500 bytes=334
2013-09-16T12:54:31.571790+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:133:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.571790+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.571790+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.571790+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-16 12:54:31] ERROR ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
2013-09-16T12:54:31.571790+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:140:in `variation'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.571790+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:24:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.571790+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.571790+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.571790+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.571790+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.571970+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.571970+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.553228+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-5c6e8eba841451fd8e44660093bd224e.css host=buyabrickonline.herokuapp.com fwd="115.188.114.182" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=9ms status=500 bytes=334
2013-09-16T12:54:31.885143+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-16 12:54:31] ERROR ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
2013-09-16T12:54:31.885143+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:140:in `variation'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.885143+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:24:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.885143+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.885143+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:133:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.885143+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.885143+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.885143+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.885290+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.885290+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.885143+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.885143+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-09-16T12:54:31.892947+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=buyabrickonline.herokuapp.com fwd="115.188.114.182" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=334
2013-09-16T12:54:35.755436+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-09-16T12:54:35.755436+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-16 12:54:35] ERROR ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
2013-09-16T12:54:35.755436+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:140:in `variation'
2013-09-16T12:54:35.755436+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:133:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:35.755436+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:24:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:35.755436+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:35.755436+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:35.755436+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:35.755436+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:35.755436+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-09-16T12:54:35.755629+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-09-16T12:54:35.755629+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-09-16T12:54:35.757107+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=buyabrickonline.herokuapp.com fwd="115.188.114.182" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=10ms status=500 bytes=334
2013-09-16T12:54:43.891290+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:43.891290+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:43.891290+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-16 12:54:43] ERROR ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
2013-09-16T12:54:43.891290+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:140:in `variation'
2013-09-16T12:54:43.891290+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:133:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:43.891290+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:24:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:43.891290+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:43.891290+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:54:43.891290+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-09-16T12:54:43.891290+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-09-16T12:54:43.891475+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-09-16T12:54:43.891475+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-09-16T12:54:43.895919+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=buyabrickonline.herokuapp.com fwd="115.188.114.182" dyno=web.1 connect=29ms service=8ms status=500 bytes=334
2013-09-16T12:56:14.421956+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:24:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:56:14.421956+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:140:in `variation'
2013-09-16T12:56:14.421956+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:133:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:56:14.421956+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:56:14.421956+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:56:14.421956+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:56:14.421956+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-16 12:56:14] ERROR ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
2013-09-16T12:56:14.421956+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-09-16T12:56:14.421956+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-09-16T12:56:14.421956+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-09-16T12:56:14.422129+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-09-16T12:56:14.422129+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-09-16T12:56:14.423497+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=buyabrickonline.herokuapp.com fwd="115.188.114.182" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=334
2013-09-16T13:00:55.666613+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-09-16T13:00:55.666613+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-09-16T13:00:55.666613+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-09-16T13:00:55.666613+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-16 13:00:55] ERROR ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
2013-09-16T13:00:55.666613+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:140:in `variation'
2013-09-16T13:00:55.666613+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:133:in `call'
2013-09-16T13:00:55.666613+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:24:in `call'
2013-09-16T13:00:55.666613+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-09-16T13:00:55.666613+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-09-16T13:00:55.666613+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-09-16T13:00:55.666801+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-09-16T13:00:55.666801+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-09-16T13:00:56.096391+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-16 13:00:56] ERROR ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
2013-09-16T13:00:56.096391+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:140:in `variation'
2013-09-16T13:00:56.096391+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:133:in `call'
2013-09-16T13:00:56.096391+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:24:in `call'
2013-09-16T13:00:56.096391+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-09-16T13:00:56.096391+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-09-16T13:00:56.096391+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-09-16T13:00:56.096391+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-09-16T13:00:56.096391+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-09-16T13:00:56.096391+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-09-16T13:00:56.096581+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-09-16T13:00:56.096581+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-09-16T13:00:56.100801+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=buyabrickonline.herokuapp.com fwd="115.188.114.182" dyno=web.1 connect=59ms service=7ms status=500 bytes=334
2013-09-16T13:00:55.669488+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-5c6e8eba841451fd8e44660093bd224e.css host=buyabrickonline.herokuapp.com fwd="115.188.114.182" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=334
```

Webrick chucking errors at me

[image]

Ok.. this issue above is do with my SSL config... fixed that now the issue is...

[image]

Comment: can you share the contents of `heroku logs` with the stack trace?

Comment: sure thing. Look at post now.

Comment: Hmm, looks like a problem initialising webrick.  What happens if you try and run the production server on your local environment? `RAILS_ENV=production rails s`  Does it boot or die?

Comment: but the page loads. Just not the css file?

Comment: Soory for the lots of back and forth, but what is the `grid` method in your controller and the `grid.html.erb` seems to be an odd mix of javascript and css.  The best next step I can come up with would be to temporarily move better_errors into the main level of your Gemfile and use that to poke around....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I cloned your repo and had a play around locally, here are the steps I took to make it work.

`production.rb`

Commented out this line as it doesn't seem necessary on other

```
  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  #config.serve_static_assets = false
```

Commented out this line too

```
  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  #config.assets.compile = true
```

And this one

```
  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  #config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "nill" # for apache
```

`RAILS_ENV=production rails s` now seems to be working just fine.

I also removed the precompiled assets by running `rake assets:clobber`, I find that it's easier to let Heroku do the precompile during heavy development as I find it's too easy to forget to precompile and add to git before pushing to Heroku...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to precompile your assets by running:

```
heroku run bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```